# C++ async only uses 2 cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I am using async to run a method simultaneously, but when I check my CPU, it shows that only 2 of 8 are in use. My CPU utilization is about 13%-16% the whole time. 
The function async should create a new thread with every call and thus should be able to use more processors or did I understand something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
for (map<string, Cell>::iterator a = cells.begin(); a != cells.end(); ++a)
{
    for (map<string, Cell>::iterator b = cells.begin(); b != cells.end(); ++b)
    {
        if (a->first == b->first)
            continue;

        if (_paths.count("path_" + b->first + "_" + a->first) > 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        tmp = "path_" + a->first + "_" + b->first;
        auto future = async(launch::async, &Pathfinder::findPath, this, &a->second, &b->second, collisionZone);
        _paths[tmp] = future.get();
    }
}
```

Did I get the concept wrong?

EDIT:

Thanks guys, I figured it out now. I didn't know, that calling .get() on the future would wait for it to finish, which afterwards seems only logical...

However, I edited my code now:

```
    for (map<string, Cell>::iterator a = cells.begin(); a != cells.end(); ++a)
{
    for (map<string, Cell>::iterator b = cells.begin(); b != cells.end(); ++b)
    {
        if (a->first == b->first)
            continue;

        if (_paths.count("path_" + b->first + "_" + a->first) > 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        tmp = "path_" + a->first + "_" + b->first;
        mapBuffer[tmp] = async(launch::async, &Pathfinder::findPath, this, &a->second, &b->second, collisionZone);
    }
}

for (map<string, future<list<Point>>>::iterator i = mapBuffer.begin(); i != mapBuffer.end(); ++i)
{
    _paths[i->first] = i->second.get();
}
```

It works. Now it spawns threads properly and uses all my cpu power. You saved me a lot of trouble! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no guarantees as to what decisions the OS make (at the language level).

Comment: "Did I get the concept wrong?" [Yes, you did](http://stackoverflow.com/q/600795/335858).

Comment: You're reaping the `future` right after spawning it.

Comment: ^and if you dont wanna "reap" it, you have to spawn the async threads yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the underlying problem:

You probably should refactor the code by splitting the loop. In the first loop, you create all the futures and put them in a map indexed by `tmp`. In the second loop, you loop over this map and get all the values from each future, storing the results in `_paths`

After the first loop, you'll have a lot of futures running in parallel, so your cores should be busy enough. If `cells` is big enough (>numCores), it may be wise to just split the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me the final bit I needed for understanding the async function. I also want to thank the others.

Answer (score 1):

`std::async` runs specified function asynchronously and returns immediately. That's it.

It's up to compiler how to do it. Some compilers create thread per async operation, some compilers have thread pool.

I recommend to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775870/2786682

By the way, your code does not really use `std::async` as you're making synchronous call to `future.get` just after 'spawning' the async operation.

Answer (score 1):

YES, you did get it wrong. Parallel code requires some thoughts before writing any code.

Your code creates a `future` (which may and probably will spawn a new thread), and immediately after that, you force the newly created `future` to stop (call its `.get()`method), to synchronize, and have it returning a result.

So, with this strategy, your code will not utilize more than 2 cpu cores ever, at any point in time. It can't.

Actually, most of the time your code utilizes only a single core!

The trick is "to parallelize" your code.