# function with std::async does not make use of multiple cores on Linux

Tags: c++, quantitative-finance, stdasync

I was checking out a [session](https://youtu.be/NeGO8lWDgyo) by Daniel Hanson from CppCon2019. It is about applying modern C++ in quantitative finance. One of the key ideas is to run the equity price generator asynchronously so that the Monte-Carlo process can be greatly accelerated.

This function in particular caught my attention. It works as intended in Visual Studio but fails to run asynchronously on my Linux machine.

```cpp
void MCEuroOptPricer::computePriceAsync_() {
  // a callable object that returns a `std::vector<double>` when called
  EquityPriceGenerator epg(spot_, numTimeSteps_, timeToExpiry_, riskFreeRate_,
                           volatility_);
  // fills `seeds_` (a std::vector<int>) with `std::iota`
  generateSeeds_();

  std::vector<std::future<std::vector<double>>> futures;
  futures.reserve(numScenarios_);
  for (auto &seed : seeds_) {
    futures.push_back(std::async(epg, seed));
  }

  std::vector<double> discountedPayoffs;
  discountedPayoffs.reserve(numScenarios_);
  for (auto &future : futures) {
    double terminalPrice = future.get().back();
    double payoff = payoff_(terminalPrice);
    discountedPayoffs.push_back(discFactor_ * payoff);
  }

  double numScens = static_cast<double>(numScenarios_);
  price_ =
      quantity_ * (1.0 / numScens) *
      std::accumulate(discountedPayoffs.begin(), discountedPayoffs.end(), 0.0);
}
```

I was using `clang++ -std=c++17 -O3`. This paralleled version runs even slower than the not-paralleled version. It was not using multiple cores according to htop. I tried to call `std::async` with `std::launch::async` but it did not help either. Is it because I am missing some compiler options or Visual Studio's compiler is applying some optimization that I am unaware of? How can I make this function run asynchronously on Linux?

Not a CS major so I might just be missing something obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: it turns out that currently `std::async` is pooled on Windows, but not on UNIX-like systems. [This article](https://ddanilov.me/std-async-implementations/) by Dmitry Danilov explains this in detail.

I managed to get similar performance on WSL2 as native Windows with an implementation involving `boost/asio/thread_pool.hpp`.

```
void MCEuroOptPricer::computePriceWithPool_() {
  EquityPriceGenerator epg(spot_, numTimeSteps_, timeToExpiry_, riskFreeRate_,
                           volatility_);
  generateSeeds_();

  std::vector<double> discountedPayoffs;
  discountedPayoffs.reserve(numScenarios_);

  std::mutex mtx; // avoid data races when writing into the vector
  boost::asio::thread_pool pool(get_nprocs());
  for (auto &seed : seeds_) {
    boost::asio::post(pool, [&]() {
      double terminalPrice = (epg(seed)).back();
      double payoff = payoff_(terminalPrice);
      mtx.lock();
      discountedPayoffs.push_back(discFactor_ * payoff);
      mtx.unlock();
    });
  }
  pool.join();

  double numScens = static_cast<double>(numScenarios_);
  price_ =
      quantity_ * (1.0 / numScens) *
      std::accumulate(discountedPayoffs.begin(), discountedPayoffs.end(), 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Might be time to take a look at g++ ;)  Relevant links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069313/421195, https://reviews.llvm.org/D52193

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you for the comment! After some digging, it seems that somehow std::async uses thread pool ONLY on Windows. g++ and clang++ on WSL, clang++ on macOS, they both give me a slower paralleled version. On the other hand clang++ and VC++ on Windows are working as intended. Also if I force to run the generator with launch::async, the program will throw a system_error when I supply a relatively large numScene. I believe I need to read much more about multithreading before I could get it to work on Linux.