# c++11 threads vs async

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdthread, stdasync

Consider the following two snippets of code where I am trying to launch 10000 threads:

**Snippet 1**

```
    std::array<std::future<void>, 10000> furArr_;
    try
    {
        size_t index = 0;
        for (auto & fut : furArr_)
        {
            std::cout << "Created thread # " << index++ << std::endl;
            fut = std::async(std::launch::async, fun);
        }
    }
    catch (std::system_error & ex)
    {
        std::string str = ex.what();
        std::cout << "Caught : " << str.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
    // I will call get afterwards, still 10000 threads should be active by now assuming "fun" is time consuming
```

**Snippet 2**

```
    std::array<std::thread, 10000> threadArr;
    try
    {
        size_t index = 0;
        for (auto & thr : threadArr)
        {
            std::cout << "Created thread # " << index++ << std::endl;
            thr = std::thread(fun);
        }
    }
    catch (std::system_error & ex)
    {
        std::string str = ex.what();
        std::cout << "Caught : " << str.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
```

The first case always succeeds .i.e. I am able to create 10000 threads and then I have to wait for all of them to finish. In the second case, almost always I end up getting an exception("resource unavailable try again") after creating 1600+ threads.

With a launch policy of std::launch::async, I thought that the two snippets should behave the same way. How different std::async with a launch policy of async is from launching a thread explicitly using std::thread?

I am on Windows 10, VS2015, binary is built in x86 release mode.

Comment: Snippet 1 doesn't create 10000 threads. It creates 10000 units of work, which are queued for execution on the system-maintained pool of a few threads. Have `fun` print `std::this_thread::get_id()`, see for yourself.

Comment: Wow that is neat. I din't know that!. The thread ids indeed seem to repeat.
So potentially using async is like having your own thread pool. Is that analogy correct?

Comment: Well, the standard doesn't specify exactly how `std::async` is to be implemented; but a typical implementation would in fact employ a thread pool.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, thanks to [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) for giving me the direction for this answer.

When we use `std::async` (with async launch policy), we are saying:

> “I want to get this work done on a separate thread”.

When we use `std::thread` we are saying:

> “I want to get this work done on a new thread”.

The subtle difference means that `async` (is usually) implemented using thread pools. Which means if we have invoked a method using `async` multiple times, often the thread id inside that method will repeat i.e. `async` allocates multiple jobs to the same set of threads from the pool. Whereas with `std::thread`, it never will.

This difference means that launching threads explicitly will be potentially more resource intensive (and thus the exception) than using `async` with `async` launch policy.

Comment: I think there was some discussion that using a thread-pool to implement `std::async` was not strictly compliant with the standard: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-promises-and-challenges-of-stdasync-task-based-parallelism-in-c11/. I also remember that at least gcc 4.8 does not use a thread-pool, so "usually" may be a bit too optimistic. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666443/which-stdasync-implementations-use-thread-pools.