# Does C++ async use a thread pool when building for macOS with Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, xcode8

Using the standard development tools and compilers for the platform[1], does `std::async` spawn a new OS thread for each background job or does it use a thread pool or some system based on work stealing task queues?

1. Xcode, Clang/LLVM

Comment: This is going to be a compiler-specific implementation detail, it does not (necessarily) have anything to do with your OS

Comment: @CoryKramer Good point. Edited question body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An application built with the standard toolchain for the platform (Xcode/Clang) does not use a thread pool. The base of the stack of a task launched with `std::async` contains std::thread and pthread calls.

[image: Stack trace showing async job running on a dedicated OS thread]

On exit, each job calls `pthread_exit()` to kill the thread running it.

[image]

Xcode 8.3.3 also uses an OS thread per job launched with `std::async` when building for iOS (Tested on original iPad Pro 9.7" target).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No major standard implementation currently uses thread pools for `std::async`. Despite that notion that implementation could do this, this would be extremely hard in practice for implementations, and I do not foresee it in any near future.

Comment: Did the Visual Studio one back off from doing this?

Comment: MSVC one certainly seems to be reusing threads from a thread pool. Check this very nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666443/which-stdasync-implementations-use-thread-pools)

Comment: @Programist, just plain read of documentation doesn't [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/future-functions) this statement: `If policy is launch::async, the function **creates a thread** that evaluates INVOKE(dfn, dargs..., Ty). The function returns after it creates the thread without waiting for results. If the system can't **start a new thread**, the function throws a system_error that has an error code of resource_unavailable_try_again.`

Comment: @ahcox, their documentation certainly indicates this.

Comment: ok. my understanding was wrong then. it spawns a new single thread for each background task.

Comment: to add a little more, it is very similar to what Android's [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) does in java.

Comment: @Programist, last time I checked the Android source code (~2010) AsyncTask was using a thread pool.